# 2-d lighting day/night cycle

Tags: xna, lighting

Off the back of this [post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40481/2-d-lighting-theory) in which I asked two questions and received one answer, which I accepted as a valid answer. I have decided to re-ask the outstanding question.

I have implemented light points with shadow casting as shown [here](http://www.funhazard.com/xna-resources.html) but I would like an overall map light with no point/light source.

The map setup is a top-down 2-d 50X50 pixel grid.

**How would I go about implementing a day/night cycle lighting across a map?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Do Day Night Cycles Work?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/39961/how-do-day-night-cycles-work)

Comment: I did search i think that post relates more to 3-d. but i'm sorry if its duplicated :(

Comment: The concepts are the same. Changing the visuals of your game to represent more or less light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your answer floAr I'm be up-voting your answer for giving me the term I was searching for:

*Ambient lighting* - lighting which is from no particular source but which is background lighting across all entities.

I've found [this blog post with some very simple code](http://nakatodev.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/xna-ambient-2d-light.html) which I'll be trying later.

this is the key for me:

**new Color(ambientColor.R / 255f * ambient, ambientColor.G / 255f * ambient, ambientColor.B / 255f * ambient);**

From the blog post:

(the approach is to modify the color of every sprite when drawing it)

> Add to the top of your game class:
>
> ```
> float ambient = 1f;  
> Color ambientColor = Color.White;
> ```
>
> In the Update method:
>
> ```
> KeyboardState c = Keyboard.GetState();  
> if (c.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))  
> {  
>    ambient -= 0.01f;  
>    if (ambient <= 0)  
>       ambient = 1f;  
> }
> ```
>
> And finally, to apply ambient lighting to sprites:
>
> ```
> Color drawColor = new Color(ambientColor.R / 255f * ambient, ambientColor.G / 255f * ambient, ambientColor.B / 255f * ambient); 
> spriteBatch.Begin();  
> spriteBatch.Draw(mySprite, new Vector2(0,0), drawColor);  
> spriteBatch.End();
> ```
>
> As you see, it's very easy :) With this, you could simulate for example day cycle.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look into ambient lightning. This means you set a light color which is applied to all elements.
This could be done in several ways.
If you are using a shader for postprocessing you can add it there as a parameter and just change it to simulate day and night cycles.

A nice example was shown [here](http://www.xnamag.de/forum/viewtopic.php?p=68025) (its in german, but maybe the source will help you a bit).
It basically uses blend states to mix up different render targets containing the light sources.